# Trouble deleting certain nested JSON objects in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, twitter, nested

I am trying to iterate through a list of nested JSON objects (returned from the twitter rest API via tweepy.api.search) and delete certain objects.  I have a list of objects to keep.  I wish to specify which dictionary objects to keep rather than which to delete because different tweets have different keys.  They all have some keys such as "text", "created_at", etc... but there are other keys that only certain tweets have.

I am running into two problems.

1) I cannot delete a dictionary item while iterating through the dictionary

2) Many of the dictionary objects contain nested lists and dictionaries which I am having trouble accessing

A small portion of the JSON file I'm iterating through:

```
{
"statuses": [
    {
        "contributors": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "created_at": "Thu Nov 12 01:28:07 +0000 2015",
        "entities": {
            "hashtags": [],
            "symbols": [],
            "urls": [
                {
                    "display_url": "twitter.com/thehill/status\u2026",
                    "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/thehill/status/664581138975989761",
                    "indices": [
                        139,
                        140
                    ],
                    "url": "https://t.co/9zfkg2FixZ"
                }
            ],
            "user_mentions": [
                {
                    "id": 2517854953,
                    "id_str": "2517854953",
                    "indices": [
                        3,
                        19
                    ],
                    "name": "It'sAlwaysPolitical",
                    "screen_name": "politicspodcast"
                }
            ]
        },
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "favorited": false,
        "geo": null
}
]
}
```

Each item in the list "statuses" is one tweet, and there are 100 tweets returned per call.

List of items that I want to keep:

```
keepers_list = [tweetlist["statuses"][i]["coordinates"],
                tweetlist["statuses"][i]["created_at"],
                tweetlist["statuses"][i]["entities"]["urls"]
                ]
```

I am trying to do:

```
for item in tweetlist:
    if item not in keepers_list:
        del item
```

I have tried this exact code and more variations on it/different methods than I can recall, but cannot make it work.  I have looked at numerous stack exchange posts on this topic, but have not been able to adapt any of them to my purpose.

I have tried using

```
for key in dict.iterkeys(): ...
for value in dict.itervalues(): ...
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
```

but I cannot make any of them work for what I want to do.

Any help, or just a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Never delete items in a list while iterating over it, you can either

Make a copy of the list to iterate over:

```
for item in tweetlist[:]:
    ...
```

Save your desired results in another list:

```
keep = []
for item in tweetlist:
    if item in keepers_list:
        keep.append(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

My general rule of thumb in Python is, if I find myself using a loop, to search for a different approach.  In this case, to use a dictionary comprehension, based on the original entry:

```
keep = {key:tweet_list[key] for key in tweet_list.keys() if key in keepers_list}
```

Unless the original dataset is so large that it has to be processed in place, a comprehension is generally fast and, if relatively short, self documenting enough to be easily understood.

Comment: I believe `key:tweet_list[k]` should be `key:tweet_list[key]`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter out a dict you can do something like:

```
for k in dict.keys():
    if k not in keepers_list:
        del(dict[k])
print dict
```